# Update table using ASP.Net Console App c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

trying to update a column of null values with instagramIds, this is my current approach but the console app just keeps running and doesn't update any values in the database.

```cs
public static async Task<InstagramUser> ScrapeInstagram(string url)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // create html document
            var htmlBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDocument.LoadHtml(htmlBody);

            // select script tags
            var scripts = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/script");

            // preprocess result
            var uselessString = "window._sharedData = ";
            var scriptInnerText = scripts[0].InnerText
                .Substring(uselessString.Length)
                .Replace(";", "");

            // serialize objects and fetch the user data
            dynamic jsonStuff = JObject.Parse(scriptInnerText);
            dynamic userProfile = jsonStuff["entry_data"]["ProfilePage"][0]["graphql"]["user"];

            List<String> columnData = new List<String>();


            //Update database query 
            string connectionString = @"Server=myProject-dev-db.cothtpanmcn7.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com;Database=Projectdb;User Id=testadmin;Password=U8gs7vb7C7yvakXf;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Trusted_Connection=False;";

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                //get null values from database  
                string query = "Select * from ApplicationUser where InstagramId is null";
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con))
                {
                    command.Connection.Open();

                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            columnData.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                        }
                    }
                }

                for (int index = 0; index < columnData.Count(); index++)
                {
                    //get username and scrape info 
                    var instagramInfo = new InstagramUser
                    {   
                        Id = userProfile.id,   
                    };
                    columnData.Add(instagramInfo.ToString());
                }

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update ApplicationUser Set InstagramId = '" + columnData + "'" + "where InstagramUsername =  '" + userprofile.username + "'", con);
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }

            // create an InstagramUser
            var instagramUser = new InstagramUser
            {
                FullName = userProfile.full_name,
                FollowerCount = userProfile.edge_followed_by.count,
                FollowingCount = userProfile.edge_follow.count,
                Id = userProfile.id,
                url = url
            };
            return instagramUser;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception($"Something wrong happened {response.StatusCode} - {response.ReasonPhrase} - {response.RequestMessage}");
        }
    }
}
```

My current approach is to create a list, add all instagramIDs which are null to that list. From there I add all instagramIds to that list after scraping Instagram for their usernames e.g. https://www.instagram.com/therock/?__a=1

then I update the column InstagramUsername with their instagram Ids

Comment: If you have a question, you need to ask it. Always [use parameters](https://www.dbdelta.com/why-parameters-are-a-best-practice/).

Comment: Terminology note: there's no such thing as as "ASP.NET console app". You can have an "ASP.NET app" which is a web-based application, **or** a ".NET Console app", which is obviously a console-based interface, nothing to do with the web. The thing they have in common is  ".NET" - i.e the framework. (ASP stands for "Active Server Pages".)

Comment: Anyway... _"I want to try"_ ... so where are you stuck with it exactly? I think we need a slightly more specific problem to work on.

Comment: Implementation note: the `SqlCommand` class is `IDisposable` by way of its parent class `DbCommand`. You should be wrapping SqlCommands in using blocks just like SqlConnections.

Comment: @ADyson sorry I thought I had explained it, I'm stuck with trying to figure out how to loop through all the null instagramIds in my database and add all the Ids based off their corresponding instagramUsernames

Comment: Ok, but within that, where are you stuck? Do you understand how to loop through the results of a query? If not then almost any ado.net tutorial would show you

Comment: I understand the foreach() but I don't understand how to update all InstagramIds which are null and match them with the correct InstagramUsernames